# Make the other image rotate when hover

Tags: html, css, image, rotation, hover

Let's say I have 2 pics. Pic A in front of pic B. I want B to rotate when I hover A. Here's my HTML code

```
<div id="nav">
<img class="button" src="images/ornament.png"/>
<img class="circle" src="images/profile.png"/>
</div>
```

And my CSS

```
.circle:hover .button
{
transition: 3s;
transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: rotate (360deg);
}
```

Please someone help me with this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS  currently can't transverse the DOM, therefore it wouldn't be possible in this case. You would need JavaScript in order to do that.

In pure CSS, you could, however, do the opposite. Changing the order of the markup:

```
<img class="circle" src="//.." />
<img class="button" src="//.." />
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gMXQ/1/)

Either use the adjacent sibling combinator, `+`, or the general sibling combinator, `~`.

```
.circle:hover + .button {
    transition: 3s;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate (360deg);
}
```

Using the same HTML, you could also change the visual order by floating the element(s) in the opposite direction. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gMXQ/)

Aside from this, it's worth noting that you were using `.circle:hover .button`; which will select an element with class `button` that is a descendant of a element with class `.circle` this is in the `:hover` state.

Comment: I was in a hurry..!! i have deleted my answer..and upvoted yours..!!